# OpenERP one2many issue

Tags: odoo

I have the following:

```
shipment_obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking.in').browse(cr, uid, context.get('active_id'))
```

This returns correct object, I can access properties, but when I access the O2m field "move_lines", it returns None object and cannot iterate.

Do I need special way to access the products for the specific incoming shipment?

This is in existing OpenERP:

```
    'move_lines': fields.one2many('stock.move', 'picking_id', 'Internal Moves', states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}),
    'product_id': fields.related('move_lines', 'product_id', type='many2one', relation='product.product', string='Product'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this which solves the problem:

```
if context is not None and context.get('active_id'):
```

it is the way I thought the method was called that didn't need to check context and active_id since there would always be a context and active_id, I was wrong.

Comment: I dont think we need to use the line you have added.shipment_obj.move_lines will give us a list of objects if there is any record or or an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

`stock.picking.in` , `stock.picking.out` and `stock.picking` are actually the same table `stock_picking` and `stock.picking` is considered as the base of both `stock.picking.in` and `stock.picking.out`. I think this functionality still have some issues and it is solved in openerp v8.So when you need to browse the object, use the `stock.picking` whether you are browsing for `stock.picking.in` nor `stock.picking.out`

Answer (score 0):

when using

```
shipment_obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking.in').browse(cr, uid, context.get('active_id'))
```

here you will get a list of browse records, you can access the one2many field move_lines like

```
for shipment_id in shipment_obj:
    move_lines = shipment_id.move_lines
```

here you will get the move_lines of each records of the list...

Comment: and here is the result:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'move_lines'

Comment: browse returns an object if a single ID is passed, and a list of objects if a list of IDs is passed. this is from docs. anyhow, I found the issue, but right now I'm not sure what to think of it. the code in original OP works, but only if I add a conditional element, which I'm scratching my head about at the moment. for line in shipment_obj.move_lines: line.property etc... works, but only if I check if shipment_obj.move_lines is not None before the loop.